# Ignore Ctrl-L in WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts, richtextbox

How can I ignore/block/remove the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> keyboard shortcut from a WPF [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx)?

Right-now, this is bound to the [AlignLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.editingcommands.alignleft.aspx) [EditingCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.editingcommands.aspx).  I'd like to use this keyboard shortcut for something else (delete line) in the RichTextBox.

I'm currently handling the keyDown event, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> never makes it through.  In other words, I can respond to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd>, for example, no problem, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> is already gobbled up by the control.

```
    private void richTextBoxMain_KeyDown (object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if ( Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.L)
            {
                 // never gets here.
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this in your page load method (or somewhere suitable)

```
KeyBinding keyBinding = new KeyBinding(ApplicationCommands.NotACommand, Key.L, 
                                                         ModifierKeys.Control);
richTextBoxMain.InputBindings.Add(keyBinding);
```

That will prevent `CTRL + L` from invoking the command it usually does (due to the `NotACommand` enum). The code you currently have in your `KeyDown` method should now work.

Comment: I have System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox....It shows me an error at line richTextBoxMain.InputBindings.Add(keyBinding);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply handle the CommandBinding on the RichtextBox control like the following (code behind or xaml):

```
richTextBoxMain.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(EditingCommands.ToggleBold, NullOnCommand, NullOnCanExecuteCommand));


private static void NullOnCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

private static void NullOnCanExecuteCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = false;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

All [RichTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?view=netframework-4.8) shortcuts can be disable by using [ShortcutsEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.shortcutsenabled?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TextBoxBase_ShortcutsEnabled)

C# code:

```
    RichTextBody.ShortcutsEnabled = false;
```

Vb.net code:

```
    RichTextBody.ShortcutsEnabled = False
```

The default shortcuts are:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> - undo

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> - copy

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> - paste

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> - delete

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> - [Align current line to the left, AlignLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.editingcommands.alignleft)

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Insert</kbd> - paste

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> - [Align current line to the right](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.editingcommands.alignright?view=netframework-4.8)

You can process the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> the in the KeyPress event

C# code:

vb.net code:

To disable only the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: the property you suggest is only available for the winforms control.  This question is about the wpf variant.